# Initializing typedef arrays in structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct, typedef

I'm making a Camera struct. the struct use a `vec3` which is defined with `typedef float vec3[3]`.

To initialize a `vec3` I do `vec3 vector = {0.,0.,0.};`

My `Cameras` struct is like this:

```
typedef struct Cameras {
    vec3 eye;
    vec3 target
} Camera;
```

but when I do:

```
Camera cam;
cam.eye = { .5, 1., 0. };
```

it crashes and the compiler tells me: `expression must be modifiable`.

I thought it was an error with pointer but no, and replacing `vec3 eye` to `vec3 * eye` and `cam->eye = {.5,1.,0.}` changes nothing.

Am I creating the struct the wrong way or is a really common issue C and I'm just blind?

here my goal is not only to initalise the array, but also accessing the data and modifing/passing into function after the creation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initialize values of array in a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856045/initialize-values-of-array-in-a-struct)

Comment: @static_cast not fully a dubplicate because i want also to acces the var after creating it, seem like the only option i've found it doing array[0], array[1], ect..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because after the line `cam` is defined, subsequent "assignments" are no longer *initializations*.

To *initialize* an instance, you must put the "assignment" at the same place where it's defined:

```
Camera cam = { {.5, 1., 0.} };
```

or specifying member:

```
Camera cam = { .eye = {.5, 1., 0.} };
```

Note that this will also automatically zero-initialize `cam.target` as no initial values are specified for it.

Comment: is it the same when you want to use struct after the init ?

Comment: @Cewein No. You can only assign like this during initialization, not at any point afterwards.

Comment: to use it afer, i'm try to cast it, seem to not work

Comment: regarding: `{1.0, 2.0, 3.0}`  This is defining 3 `double` literals.  To define 3 float literals use: `{1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f}`  Note the `f` trailing each literal value

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is obvious, type of `vec3` is `float [3]` - array type and you certainly cannot "assign" to array types.

You can use the initialization as mentioned by [iBug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53885945/2173917) in another answer. However, with a small *trick*, you'll be able to use the assignment, also. This would need the usage of a pointer and [compound literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Compound_literals).

You need to change the `typedef` to `vec3`

```
 typedef float* vec3;
```

so as to make it a `float *` and then, you can use compound literal to assign the values, like

```
cam.eye = (float [3]){ .5, 1., 0. };
cam.target = (float [3]){ .45, 2.5, 0.9 }; // just some other values.
```

The primary benefit of using this approach is, you are not limited to only "initialization", you can perform the assignment at any time.

**P.S.** - [Compound literals are modifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36676149/2173917), so you do not lose any operation capabilities.

**P.P.S.**

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.2.5/ P12

> ```
> "/tmp/fileXXXXXX" 
>  (char []){"/tmp/fileXXXXXX"} 
>  (const char []){"/tmp/fileXXXXXX"}
> ```
>
> The first always has static storage duration
> and has type array of char, but need not be modifiable; the last two
> have automatic storage duration when they occur within the body of a
> function, and **the first of these two is modifiable.**

Comment: The only problem is that the compound literal will be placed in the RO memory. Any attempt to modify them will be the UB (same as string literals)

Comment: @P__J__ What? How? IIRC, CLs are modifiable Lvalue.

Comment: @P__J__ So, you're saying the standard is wrong? :) Chapter §6.5.2.5/P12.

Comment: I just look at the real compiler output. As I see it is in the .rodata segment.

Comment: @P__J__ That can be answered / reasoned by compiler docs. I'm talking from Spec perspective.

Comment: And I from the real programmer use. It is one of the reasons I do not like them (I only use them if I am not going to modify it). Better to avoid - they are not in the common use and as you see it hard to relay on them.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer more "descriptive" initialization - I like members to be specified - the code is easier to read for humans.

```
typedef float vec3[3];

typedef struct Cameras {
    vec3 eye;
    vec3 target;
} Camera;

Camera c = 
{
  .eye = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0},   
  .target = {4.0, 5.0, 6.0},   
};

Camera c1 = 
{
  .target = {4.0, 5.0, 6.0},   
};

Camera c2 = 
{
  .eye = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0},   
};
```