# How to pass "dummy" argument to a function in C?

Tags: c, arguments, parameter-passing

For the purpose of the question I don't report all the code but just the significant details.
I have this function:

```
void foo(/* SOME OTHER ARGS */ int* len);
```

This function (that I can't edit and don't want edit since in other circumstances I need `len`) creates a file and modifies `len` parameter accordingly. In some occasion I don't need `len` at all, and hence my question is: is there a way to pass a hard-coded dummy parameter **without** declaring a dummy variable just for this purpose?

Comment: If `foo` allows it, you might just pass NULL.  If `foo` does not allow it, you will need a valid address.

Comment: Why exactly can't you declare a dummy parameter/parameters? A variable named "dummy" is a perfect example of self-documenting code. It is common that function are written to accept NULL for optional parameters.

Comment: Are you allowed to modify the function _implementation_ (not the function _prototype_)?

Answer (score 1):

Elements of compound literals are modifyable, so you can pass its address if the function require valid addresses.

```
foo(/* SOME OTHER ARGS */, (int[]){0});
```

Note that most arrays in expressions are converted to an address of their first elements.

More information: [c99 - Why are compound literals in C modifiable - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676149/why-are-compound-literals-in-c-modifiable)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't intend to use `len`, and `foo()` is geared up to handle a null-value passed through `len`, you can call the function like

```
foo (validparams, NULL);
```

Comment: Maybe.  But if `foo` requires an address this may lead to a run time error.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Just updated that part. Also, if `foo()` requires `len` to be a valid address, it's hard to see that it'll be unused.